# Is there a way such that the Objects inside the log.debug are converted in JSON format

Tags: java, logging

My application(old and very complex) has logging with SL4J with normal output as tradional logging. Is there any other way of logging for my application such that

```
  log.info("Employee Object", employee);

  log.debug("Employee Object", employee);

  log.trace("Employee Object", employee);
```

the employee objects convert into JSON format.

I know the packages as below available to convert the Logs to **JSON** format, but would like to know if there are more because there are lot of customization required inside the application code for the logs when I use the below packages

1. Logstash-Logback-encoder
2. Elastic Logstash

Comment: Why not override the `toString()` method of your objects?

Comment: we are using lombok and again I should make application code changes

Comment: What is your current logger implementation?

Comment: SL4J and logback is used

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use Jackson to convert objects into JSON objects. You can create a custom convertor method where you can implement all the logic for converting from POJO to JSON.
Might this help you: https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Comment: the link shows what we can only convert a single object into JSON but in a complex application we have more than, 1000 of debug statements with objects passed. I am thinking of a generic class which converts every POJO   added in logs to JSON

Comment: So, do you have multiple objects types?

Comment: Do you mean as `log.info("Employee Object", employee)` and `log.debug("Organization Object", organization)`, **YES**